# Power transformer with four similar secondary windings connected in parallel

Tags: transformer, parallel, high-current, esr

I need help with the math that is glossed over in nearly every explanation I can find on the web.

I have a transformer with a toroid core and primary that were professionally assembled and rated at 2150 VA. I have wound four separate secondaries. I am getting 0.8 V per turn on the secondary and 16 turns yield ~14.4 V with a geometry that requires about 18 feet of 2 AWG solid copper magnet wire rated at 0.1563 Ω/1000 ft. That gives me ~2.8134 mΩ in the copper. Each secondary, in isolation, does show about a 0.4 V drop at 145 A so I'm comfortable with that number.

What I would like to see is the math that computes the current in each winding and the voltage drop across each effective series resistances before I hook these windings up in parallel and try to draw 480 A from it.

I've done the math before with two sources, but never a third or fourth, and it seems no one else has either. I've tried brute force Kirchoff's law in this funky hyper bridge circuit system of equations but I cannot get answers where Vw1 = Vw2 = Vw3 = Vw4. Clearly I am not as good with algebra as I thought I was.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwg2kC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can some one show me the math? I want to plug in fractionally dissimilar values to see where competing current flows in my secondaries become a concern.

Edit: I know this much secondary current will push this core into saturation. Right now I just need to know if I can manage the expected variance of these multiple secondaries, I will invest in a higher-rated core later. I didn't mean to frighten anybody.

Comment: A thevenin equivalent would be great too, if possible.

Comment: Simulation seems ideal for this.

Comment: (um - 2150 VA < 14.4 V * 480 A.) (Just *what* are you going to power?)

Comment: @greybeard I think he is saying AC Voltage (VAC), not VA (volt-amperes)

Comment: (@RogerDodger Could have been VA *capacitive*, but probably you are right. Still - 2150 V? Another mystery.)

Comment: Also, am I hallucinating or reading something wrong, each winding at full load has around 60W of conduction loss, let alone whatever the AC loss is going to be depending on what/how this is used?

Comment: @greybeard no I did mean VA. I will be investing in a higher rated core once I am convinced I have a good handle on the tolerance problem. Power dissipated in the windings is exactly what I'm worried about, if my other windings vary too much.

Comment: (`\$V_{AC}\$` yields \$V_{AC}\$)

Comment: (Did you try to set up a simulation? The schematic is a good start to using the CircuitLab simulator: Replace the inductors by voltage sources of differing voltages (same frequency&phase), add a load (or not) and do a time domain simulation for two periods.)

Comment: `what to do with source currents that are not equal` same as with equal currents: add all currents. Or let a simulator spell all that out for you.

Comment: Tweaking the Norton equivalent calculations has made me decide to fine tune my secondary windings. I am going to add a balancing step to my final assembly. I will put a temporary test resister between leg 1 and 2. I can adjust the second winding more or less to get zero volts dropped across my test resister. I will repeat with 1 and 3, and 1 and 4.

Comment: At 7kVA, you may contact your regional transformer constructor. Rather than dealing with differences, try to avoid them in the fist place. While it's worse with toroids, consider a cylindrical *coil former* (out of usually two, U-core or cut-band - my diction may be off in English). If one secondary would fill one layer, don't wind it that way. Split it in the middle, use four terminals (mounting opportunities for terminals being one (sole?) advantage of U cores). Same for the "second secondary" on this coil former. Wire as one secondary one "inner" and "outer" half each in series.

Comment: @greybeard, I wound them interleaved so their geometries are already nearly identical. The fourth winding came out a layer one turn earlier than the other three and it was a tad less than the other three so I just wound a fraction more to compensate. I reason that my volts/turn far out ways the extra resistance of a few inches of wire. All four windings are now so close that I cannot measure any bridging current between them. I was surprised how much that fourth winding was costing me. When I get on my 500 amp core, I'll be glad I went through this trouble.

Comment: (had to sub-articulate `out ways` to read *outweighs*)(Others happily parallel transformers of same voltage (and group where applicable…) up to a ratio in power of 1:3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformer secondary model you show is a Thévenin equivalent which is reasonable. The voltage source in series with a resistor is intuitive. The Norton equivalent is a current source in parallel with a resistor. The Norton model is less intuitive, but makes calculations with N secondaries trivial and therefore less error prone. Convert to Norton and redraw your 4 secondary diagram and the answer will drop out. On a more practical note: you can use 4 bridge rectifiers instead of one huge one. This won't cost extra and stops nasty circulating currents.

Comment: (`bridge rectifiers` that's why I asked about what's to be powered - AC, DC, stabilised, intermittent or constant…)

Comment: @Autistic, this is an AC project. The windings can be connected in any sensible series or parallel configuration to achieve the needed voltage or current multiples. But the output cannot be rectified, although that would have been a much simpler solution. I'm am going to try to convert these to Norton equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: I thought I was doing something wrong when I saw the Norton currents. I just needed to trust the math because the Norton resistances were ridiculously small compared to the load. Now I have a both a working Norton and Thevenin model that documents this transformer. This really was much more simple that trying brute force these equations with Kirchhoff's law.